# With spark-submit, do I need a worker running on my laptop using client mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm at a lost right now. I'm running a Spark standalone cluster **with a worker on the same box**. I'm doing this as a proof of concept so it's not ready for production yet.

## Screenshot of console

[image: Spark Master]

I spun up a large box in EC2 with 4 cores and 16GB of RAM. I go to submit a job from a different node in the same subnet (Security Group confirms all ports are good between nodes).

```
/bin/spark-submit --class SimpleApp --total-executor-cores 4 \
--executor-memory 10G --master spark://spark-test:7077 \
--deploy-mode client src/main/scala/target/scala-2.11/simple-project_2.11-1.0.jar
```

I get the following error message.

> 17/05/03 20:06:51 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

Comment: Your screenshot says there is a running application using all resources. Did you forget to stop any application?

Comment: That's the app I was trying to run.

Comment: Okey. Then seems your applications got executors to run. By the way, the message here is just a warning. Do you see any other error messages?

Comment: Nothing runs, which is why I'm baffled.

Comment: Could you show the "Applications" table on the maser UI?